# Prevent mutliple scrolling on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a webpage which is split into two panels which has scrollbars for each panel. For the left panel I have a left scroll bar and for the right panel I have a right scrollbar.

When I hover on the left panel and scroll, the moment the content of left panel is ended, the body of the right div is scrolling.

Is there any way we can stop that, I mean to stop scrolling the right panel content when I hover on left panel?

I tried the below suggestions but they didn't work.
    https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/prevent-body-scrolling-when-the-user-scrolls-on-fixed-position-div/

[Freeze body scroll when hover a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658103/freeze-body-scroll-when-hover-a-div)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of the code which is producing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could split your whole page into 2 sections, left and right. Set the width of both to whatever percentage you want and the height to 100% and add vertical scrollbars with `overflow-y: auto;`.